# CakePHP unittest mocked Auth component

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, mocking, cakephp-2.0

**Code**

```
class AclRowLevelsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        // Don't use same name as Model
        '_AclRowLevel' => array('className' => 'AclRowLevel')
    );    

    public function view() {
        $this->_AclRowLevel->checkUser();        
        ...
    }

}

class AclRowLevelComponent extends Component {

    public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->AclRowLevel = ClassRegistry::init('AclRowLevel');
    }

    public function checkUser($permission, $model) {
        $row = $this->AclRowLevel->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'model' => $model['model'],
                'model_id' => $model['model_id'],
                'user_id' => $this->controller->Auth->user('id')
            )
        ));    
    }

}

class AclRowLevelsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public function testViewAccessAsManager() {

        $AclRowLevels = $this->generate('AclRowLevels', array(
            'components' => array(
                'Auth' => array(
                    'user'
                ),
                'Session',
            )
        ));

        $AclRowLevels->Auth
            ->staticExpects($this->any())
            ->method('user')
            ->with('id')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1));

        $this->testAction('/acl_row_levels/view/Task/1');
}
```

**Problem**

The query in the AclRowLevel component requires the Auth user id. I want to simulate user_id value '1' for the unit test.
The mocked Auth method 'user' in my test is not working for the call from the component. So the user id in that query has value null.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `debug($AclRowLevels->Auth);` to check if it really was mocked. It should be a mock object. If it is not for some reason try:

```
$AclRowLevels->Auth = $this->getMock(/*...*/);
```

The code inside checkUser() should go into the model by the way. Also I doubt this has to be a component at all. This seems to be used for authorization, so why not [making it a proper authorization adapter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects)?

Comment: The Auth object is already mocked? see $this->generate. There's a reason why this code is in a component. Not everything is shown here, as it is not relevant for the problem.

Comment: No, it is not. If it really is - where?

Comment: $AclRowLevels = $this->generate... right? Could you please post exactly what I should add. I'm new to unit testing.

Comment: OK, see it now. debug($AclRowLevels->Auth); to check if it really was mocked. It should be a mock object. Also can you be a little more precise than "is not working"?

Comment: Auth is really mocked because when I Put $this->Auth->user(‘id’) in my Controller view action it does work (that is returning value 1). But $this->controller->Auth->user(‘id’) in the component is not working.

Comment: Well, did you debug the object? I'm sure it is a different instance and not mocked.

Comment: Could you give me some help on how to mock this object?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
    $AclRowLevels->Auth
        ->staticExpects($this->any())
        ->method('user')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(
            function($arg) {
                if ($arg === 'id') {
                    return 1;
                }
                return null;
            }
        ));
```